# Language Settings on Solaris machine

Tags: unix, internationalization, solaris, locale

I'm using a Solaris machine with japanese language settings. I have 6-7 different japanese language packs on my machine. The product which I'm using got installed with SJIS setting.

But while executing some commands,I'm getting an error that `LANG` value and language settings are conflicting.

The value of `LANG` was `ja` and the values inside init file are: `LANG=ja LC_All=LANG=ja_JP.PCK`

Also enlighten me on init file and its influence on the system locale.

Answer (score 1):

The string `LANG=ja LC_All=LANG=ja_JP.PCK` looks a bit suspicious. Is the value of `LC_ALL` literally `LANG=ja_JP.PCK`?

Try `LANG=ja_JP.PCK` and `LC_ALL=ja_JP.PCK`. I don't know the syntax of your init file, but if it's bourne shell, I would write something like:

```
LANG=ja_JP.PCK
LC_ALL=ja_JP.PCK
export LANG LC_ALL
```